# Flutter: 'NoSuchMethodError' is not a subtype of type String

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have an app that pulls a list of providers through JSON.

This is the JSON file.

**hospitals.json**

```
{
"Johor": [
    {
      "Name": "KLINIK TAJ (MUAR)",
      "TPA Customer ID": "1168",
      "Organization Type": "Clinic",
      "Organization Subtype": "GP",
      "Street (Billing)": "35a, jalan abdullah ",
      "City (Billing)": "muar",
      "Postal Code (Billing)": "84000",
      "State (Billing)": "Johor",
      "Country (Billing)": "Malaysia",
      "Coordinates": {
        "Latitude": "2.041875",
        "Longitude": "102.568235"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "KLINIK TAJ (PAGOH)",
      "TPA Customer ID": "1169",
      "Organization Type": "Clinic",
      "Organization Subtype": "GP",
      "Street (Billing)": "100 Main Road Pagoh",
      "City (Billing)": "Muar",
      "Postal Code (Billing)": "84600",
      "State (Billing)": "Johor",
      "Country (Billing)": "Malaysia",
      "Coordinates": {
        "Latitude": "2.148342",
        "Longitude": "102.771002"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Kedah": [
    {
      "Name": "KLINIK TAN",
      "TPA Customer ID": "8423",
      "Organization Type": "Clinic",
      "Organization Subtype": "GP",
      "Street (Billing)": "62 Jalan Raya",
      "City (Billing)": "Kulim",
      "Postal Code (Billing)": "9000",
      "State (Billing)": "Kedah",
      "Coordinates": {
        "Latitude": "5.366739",
        "Longitude": "100.553988"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "KLINIK SHAN",
      "TPA Customer ID": "1685",
      "Organization Type": "Clinic",
      "Organization Subtype": "GP",
      "Street (Billing)": "L. C. 19, Jalan Lunas,",
      "City (Billing)": "Padang Serai",
      "Postal Code (Billing)": "9000",
      "State (Billing)": "Kedah",
      "Coordinates": {
        "Latitude": "5.402193",
        "Longitude": "100.555209"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the model class of the JSON

**new_accounts_model.dart**

```
class Johor {

  List<AccountInfo> accountinfo;

  Johor({this.accountinfo});

  factory Johor.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    var accJson = json["Johor"] as List;
    List<AccountInfo> accList = accJson.map((i) => AccountInfo.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return Johor(
        accountinfo: accList
    );
  }
}

class AccountInfo{

  String name;
  String id;
  String orgtype;
  String subtype;
  String street;
  String city;
  String country;
  Coordinates coordinates;

  AccountInfo({this.name, this.id, this.orgtype, this.subtype, this.street, this.city, this.country, this.coordinates});

  factory AccountInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    return AccountInfo(
        name: json["Name"],
        id: json["TPA Customer ID"],
        orgtype: json["Organization Type"],
        subtype: json["Organization Subtype"],
        street: json["Street (Billing)"],
        city: json["City (Billing)"],
        country: json["State (Billing)"],
        coordinates: Coordinates.fromJson(json["Coordinate"])
    );
  }
}

class Coordinates{

  String lat;
  String lng;

  Coordinates({this.lat, this.lng});

  factory Coordinates.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){

    return Coordinates(
        lat: json["Latitude"],
        lng: json["Longitude"]
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the dart file used to bring out the JSON file.

**list.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:emas_app/model/new_accounts_model.dart';

Future<String> _loadAsset() async{
  return await rootBundle.loadString('Assets/hospitals.json');
}

//Not working future
Future<Johor> loadJohor() async{

  final response = await _loadAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response);

  Johor johor = new Johor.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  return johor;
}

class ProviderList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  ListState createState() {
    return new ListState();
  }
}

class ListState extends State<ProviderList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> widgets = [];

    launchMapUrl(String lat, String lng) async{
      String geoUri = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:$lat,$lng";
      if (await canLaunch(geoUri)) {
        print("Can launch");
        await launch(geoUri);
      } else {
        print("Could not launch");
        throw 'Could not launch Maps';
      }
    }

    //method to bring out dialog
    makeDialog(String address){
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => new SimpleDialog(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, top: 30.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text("Address: $address",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),
              ),
              new ButtonBar(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                      )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
      );
    }

    widgets.add(new ExpansionTile(
        title: new Text("Not working state"),
        children: <Widget>[
          new FutureBuilder<Johor>(
              future: loadJohor(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){

                  return new ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.accountinfo.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){

                        String username = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].name;
                        String address = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].street;
                        String lat = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].coordinates.lat;
                        String lng = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].coordinates.lng;

                        return new ListTile(
                            title: new Text(username),
                            trailing: new Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                                    onPressed: (){
                                      makeDialog(address);
                                    }
                                ),
                                new IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.directions),
                                    onPressed: (){
                                      launchMapUrl(lat, lng);
                                    }
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                        );
                      });
                }else if(snapshot.hasError){
                  return new Center(
                    child: new Text(snapshot.error),
                  );
                }
              })
        ]
    ));

    //empty list
    widgets.add(new ExpansionTile(
        title: new Text("Pahang")));

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Providers")),
      body: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: widgets,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error currently faced:

[image: NosuchMethod]

As the title says, the error is saying its a NoSuchMethodError. Therefore I am unsure as to what is causing this error in the first place.

My current guess is that I am not doing the Model class correctly but it could be something else.

I could really use some help in this case.

Comment: When you debug it do you know which line the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong key for `Coordinates`.
You should use `Coordinates` as its name of key in json.  But you are using Coordinate in method `factory AccountInfo.fromJson`

Update your last line of that method

```
coordinates: Coordinates.fromJson(json["Coordinates"])
```

Comment: Such a simple mistake on my end. Thanks Dhiraj everything is working fine now.